# How do I modify a SQL Server Stored Procedure in the Master dbo?

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, ssms

I ran a query to find all stored procedures in SQL Server SSMS version 18.12.1 (see below).  It returned a stored procedure from the Master database.   I know how to find those that are in the typical database by looking in Programmability/Stored Procures underneath the database.  I tried looking through the SQL Server object explorer, but cannot find it.

EDIT: Thanks to @siggemannen, I was able to find out that the System Databases "folder" was collapsed underneath the Databases folder and hiding the Master.dbo.

Here is the procedure that I used to return the list of objects with a given search pattern:

```
DECLARE @SearchString varchar(120) = 'xxxx'


DECLARE @strSQL varchar(MAX) = '
USE [?];

BEGIN
DECLARE 
    @SearchStr varchar(200) 
    SET @SearchStr = ''%' + @SearchString + '%''; 
SELECT DISTINCT
    ''?'' as db_name, o.name
    , ( CASE upper(o.xtype) 
            WHEN ''C'' THEN ''CHECK constraint''        
            WHEN ''D'' THEN ''Default or DEFAULT constraint''                       
            WHEN ''F'' THEN ''FOREIGN KEY constraint''  
            WHEN ''L'' THEN ''Log''                                                                 
            WHEN ''FN'' THEN ''Scalar function''        
            WHEN ''IF'' THEN ''Inline table-function''
            WHEN ''PK'' THEN ''PRIMARY KEY or UNIQUE constraint''
            WHEN ''P'' THEN ''Stored procedure''                                            
            WHEN ''R'' THEN ''Rule''                    
            WHEN ''RF'' THEN ''Replication filter stored procedure''            
            WHEN ''S'' THEN ''System table''            
            WHEN ''TF'' THEN ''Table function''
            WHEN ''TR'' THEN ''Trigger''                
            WHEN ''U'' THEN ''User table''      
            WHEN ''V'' THEN ''View''                    
            WHEN ''UQ'' THEN ''UNIQUE constraint (type is K)''                  
            WHEN ''X'' THEN ''Extended stored procedure''                           
        ELSE upper(o.xtype) END ) Type
    , ( CASE upper(o.xtype)
            WHEN ''PK'' THEN ( select object_name(parent_object_id) FROM sys.key_constraints (nolock) WHERE o.name=name )
            WHEN ''F'' THEN ( select object_name(parent_object_id) FROM sys.foreign_keys (nolock) WHERE o.name=name )
            WHEN ''TR'' THEN ( select object_name(parent_id) FROM sys.triggers (nolock) WHERE o.name=name )     
        ELSE '''' END ) as Parent_Object
FROM sysobjects o (nolock) 
INNER JOIN syscomments sc (nolock) ON o.id = sc.id
WHERE UPPER( text ) LIKE UPPER( @SearchStr ) AND substring(o.name,1,3)<> ''dt_'' 
GROUP BY o.name, o.xtype
END'


exec sp_msforeachdb @strSQL
GO
```

Comment: The same way master->Programmability->Stored Procedures->System Stored Procedures. Hope, you have enough permissions and know, why you need to touch them

Comment: Presmably this is a user stored procedure and not an MS shipped procedure, it's no different to any other database in that regard.

Comment: If it's a system procedure then I **strongly** suggest you leave it as is; changing them could *easily* cause significant problems on your instance.

Comment: It is not a system procedure; it is a user-created stored procedure.

Comment: @Sergey, I do not have a master database that is visible in the Object browser, so I am unclear on how to do this.   Maybe I'm using the wrong terminology ... the db_name is "master" in the procedure I am using.

Comment: Why are you using those old system views like `dbo.syscomments` and `dbo.sysobjects`? They are for compatibility with SQL Server **2000**; surely you are on a more recent version, no? You *must* be, you're using a `MAX` data type. I strongly suggest you have a read of the [System compatibility views](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-compatibility-views/system-compatibility-views-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) documentation and update to the SQL Server 2005+ system views.

Comment: This was a procedure that I found on the internet that seems to work fine on the platform I am on.  Are they obsoleted?

Comment: You have to click on "System databases" to find the master-db, if you're in SSMS that is. If not, then i'm not sure why you can't find master, it should be always accessible

Comment: Yes, those system views were made obsolete (read replaced/deprecated/put into maintenance mode), in **2005**. There's a big warning about it at the top of their documentation pages, such as [syscomments (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-compatibility-views/sys-syscomments-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16).

Comment: @siggemannen That's it!   Thank you so much for your help!   I believe the SP was created by a previous developer inside the master DB by mistake.  Because that folder was closed (and really never used by me), I didn't know that was where I could find it.

Thank you for your help and kindness.  If you want to put it as a solution, I will mark it as closed.

Comment: @TonyServies cheers, happened to me many times (i mean creating procedures in master db :))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to click on "System databases" to find the master-db, if you're in SSMS (SQL Server Management Studio) that is. If not, then i'm not sure why you can't find master, it should be always accessible.

Looks like [image: master db]